# _paq.push() was used but Matomo tracker was not initialized before the matomo.js file was loaded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, matomo

Matomo tracking fails when I try to initialize in React Component. But works well if I initialize it in the index.html. I want to initialize the matomo after some events in the component but I am getting this error:

```
matomo.js:182 _paq.push() was used but Matomo tracker was not initialized before the matomo.js file was loaded. Make sure to configure the tracker via _paq.push before loading matomo.js. Alternatively, you can create a tracker via Matomo.addTracker() manually and then use _paq.push but it may not fully work as tracker methods may not be executed in the correct order.
```

I want to load Matomo_url and Site_id from backend and then initialize the matomo tracking, here is the code:

```js
var _paq = window._paq || [];
_paq.push(["trackPageView"]);
_paq.push(["enableLinkTracking"]);
(function() {
  var u = "//{$MATOMO_URL}/";
  _paq.push(["setTrackerUrl", u + "matomo.php"]);
  _paq.push(["setSiteId", { $IDSITE }]);
  var d = document,
    g = d.createElement("script"),
    s = d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
  g.type = "text/javascript";
  g.async = true;
  g.defer = true;
  g.src = u + "matomo.js";
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(g, s);
})();
```

Initializing matomo is happening in componentDidMount of the component. I would appreciate any idea.

Comment: `_paq` needs to be a global variable. So if you define it in a function, you need to set `window._paq=_paq` in that function to make it global.

Comment: @lw1.at thanks for your comment. I forgot to look at StackOverflow again. But you are right I have appended `_paq` back to window by doing `window._paq=_paq` and then it worked well

Answer (score 2):

The Matomo tracking code needs the `_paq` variable to be a global variable for the matomo.js to work properly. If the tracking code is put inside a function, then `_paq` only exists inside that function.

To workaround that, you can add `window._paq=_paq` below the `var _paq = window._paq || [];` line.